# Hide docker repos port from artifactory

Tags: nginx, port, artifactory, docker-registry

I am using version 4.7.0 of artifactory and have configured a docker virtual repository as follows

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    ## server configuration
## add ssl entries when https has been set in config
ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/artcert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/artkey.pem;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
## server configuration
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80 ;

    server_name localhost;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-error.log;
    rewrite ^/$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

## server configuration
server {
    listen 6555 ssl;


    server_name localhost;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-error.log;
    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}


}
```

I use the following commands to psuh and pull repositories

```
docker pull localhost:6555/<my-image>:latest
docker login localhost:6555
docker push localhost:6555/<my-image>:latest
```

Is there a way I can hide the port number from the user and achieve the following

```
docker pull localhost/<my-image>:latest
docker login localhost
docker push localhost/<my-image>:latest
```

I know I can configure the repository as a subdomain and get rid of the port but that requires a wildcard certificate which is currently not an option. Can I configure nginx to hide the port?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using port 443 (which is the implicit SSL port) on the top configuration, why not use it for both Docker and web-ui access?

All you need to do is add this line:

```
 rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/$1/$2;
```

to the 443 server block too. The only difference between your 6555 configuration and the 443 one are the rewrite rules, but these can actually coexist on the same server block. Once you do that, you can even get rid of the 6555 one.

If you use port 443, you won't need to specify the port with docker commands.